# How to trigger redraw of Xamarin BindableLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a `BindableLayout` that uses a `List<PricingLevel>` as the datasource. One of the columns in the resulting layout uses a converter to derive a calculated result based on a unit price in the view model and the `PricingLevel` property of the datasource.

```
public bool IsTaxInclusive { get; set; }
public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
public List<PricingLevel> PricingLevels { get; set; }
```

If the `IsTaxInclusive` flag is switched I need to update the calculated results (note  `PropertyChanged` events are raised). But because the `PricingLevels` don't change, I'm not sure how to trigger the update. At the moment I just refresh the `PricingLevels` list which works but is not ideal. Is there a simple way to force the update?

Comment: you can raise multiple `PropertyChanged` events in the setter of any property - so if changing A causes some calculated value B to change, the setter for A can raise `PropertyChanged` events for A and B

Comment: I raised the `PropertyChanged` event on the list but it didn't work, it needed to be an observable collection and then calling the `RaiseCollectionChanged()` method triggered the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

So the fix was simple. Rather than refresh the entire list, I used a `FastObservableCollection` and called its `RaiseCollectionChanged()` method.

```
public FastObservableCollection<PricingLevel> PricingLevels { get; set; }
...
PricingLevels.RaiseCollectionChanged();
```